# My api.ai bot is NOT communicating with other users on facebook

Tags: facebook, botframework, dialogflow-es

i made a demo bot (Free version) on Api.ai and integrated it with facebook but the problem is that it doesnt't respond to anyone else except me?
Maybe it is because of the fact that i created the facebook page from my account and generated page access token...
But How can i make my bot to communicate with other users too??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bot on facebook will only respond to people you specifically add as admins or testers of your bot on developers.facebook.com.

If you want to make it available to anyone, you need to request facebook's approval for `pages_messaging` on developers.facebook.com and it will take a couple of days.